# How to preload custom colors in SWT ColorDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, native

my application users the SWT Color Cell Editor to set a color property.  This class in turn users the native color dialog - which offers preset and custom colors.

My users are frustrated because whilst the color dialog allows them to enter custom colors, the application doesn't remember these custom colors (in either Win32 or OSX).

Does anybody know of a way to pre-load native cell color selector dialogs with a set of custom colors?

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this bug has been fixed in Eclipse 3.8:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=212023

And it only took 5 years ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this. See bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21812

Comment: I suggest voting for this bug, it's pretty odd that an API for this does not exist.